# Is there any way to swap nodes in std::list?

Tags: c++

I'm implementing LRUCache, where in unordered_map I store an iterator to list. When I move the most "fresh" element to the head, I need to iterator not changed.

I need to swap exactly nodes, not values in nodes. I'm finding the way to do it.

I tried to do it with std::iter_swap, but it's just implemented as `std::swap(*it_first, *it_second)`

```
std::list<std::string> list;
list.emplace_back("first");
list.emplace_back("second");

auto it_first = list.begin();
auto it_second = ++list.begin();

std::iter_swap(it_first, it_second);

assert(list.begin() == it_second);
```

I need to swap two nodes to passed assert.

Comment: What about simply `std::swap(it_first, it_second)`?

Comment: ***Why***? What is the problem you try to solve by "swap exactly nodes"? What's wrong with swapping the values? How will you even notice if the values swere swapped or the nodes?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm implementing LRUCache, where in unordered_map I store an iterator to list. When I move the most "fresh" element to the head, I need to iterator not changed.

Comment: Please explain in more detail, what issue You are trying to solve : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Well, for objects that are neither movable nor copyable, swapping around the nodes would work, swapping the values would not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`splice` looks like it can do this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice) with something like:

```
list.splice(it_first, list, it_second);
```

That says "Splice in `it_second` from myself (`list`, the second argument), before the first node in myself". The method guarantees that "the iterators to moved elements remain valid, but now refer into `*this`, not into other.", which implies the raw nodes themselves are moved.

Comment: looks like the last argument can be left out

Comment: @vehsakul: Ah, yes. I'll tweak.